# Is there a saying in English to do ‘now’ or ‘today’?

Tags: meaning, word-request, idiom-request, proverbs

There is a saying in Hindi implies do not wait for tomorrow to do anything that you can do today.

> Kal kare so aaj kar aaj kare so ab.
> Pal men parle hogi bahuri karoge kab?

Literal translation:

> Tomorrow’s work do today, today’s work now. The moment is going to be lost, when will the work be done?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is such a saying, worded very closely to what you say in your question:

["Never put off until tomorrow what you can do today."](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+put+off+until+tomorrow)

Comment: Perhaps also "Strike while the iron is hot"? And related although not exactly the same "A stich in time saves nine."

Comment: To elaborate, @randomhead's answer is a very general-purpose idiom. "Strike while the iron is hot" emphasizes that it's better to do something today because you might not have the opportunity again in the future. "A stitch in time saves nine" emphasizes that a problem not solved today could turn into a bigger problem tomorrow.